NCAlgebra computes basic commutators
I have a function comm[x_,y_]:=x**y-y**x //. ccr;
and some canonical commutation rules ccr = a**ad -> ad**a + 1;
given these, and if I set a and ad to noncommutative, NCAlgebra should be able to simplify
comm[a + ad, a ** ad] to a - ad
am I doing something wrong or is the package just unable to do it?

This is trickier than it seems.
First, make sure to set ad non-commutative by running
SNC[ad] 

Otherwise
ccr = a ** ad -> ad ** a + 1

will be equal to

a ad -> 1 + a ad

and not

a ** ad -> 1 + ad ** a

as you are expecting.
Second, note that
comm[a + ad, a ** ad]

is equal to

-a ** ad ** (a + ad) + (a + ad) ** a ** ad

which does not match any (simple) terms in your rule. More on that next. Even after expanding
NCExpand[comm[a + ad, a ** ad]]

none of the terms in

-a ** ad^2 + a^2 ** ad - a ** ad ** a + ad ** a ** ad

will match your rule. This is because Mathematica does not know how to match a ** ad inside other terms, e.g. a^2 ** ad, which is what needs to happen. For that you can use the NCReplace family of functions. But even so, you would need to Expand/Replace a number of times before the simplification you are looking for materializes. This process is automated by the NCExpandReplaceRepeated command, and in this case
NCExpandReplaceRepeated[comm[a + ad, a ** ad], a ** ad -> ad ** a + 1]

produces

a - ad

as you would expect.

thank you it does work. I was not aware of expand replace repeated which is exactly what I need. Also the only peculiarity is that sometimes importing NCAlgebra does not set lower cap single letter symbols to non commutative as the documentation says. So I have to SNC[a] manually and if there are scalars for example comm[a f, ad] = f I am not sure if mathematica will treat f as non commutative or not. Not sure why it's malfunctioning like this I guess I just need to manually set commutative/noncommutative

It should set all lower caps to nc unless you use an option before loading, which is unlikely from what you are saying. If you have a reproducible simple case please let me know.

I am not sure how to reproduce it. I literally just import the module and it displays a message saying all lower cap single letter symbols are set to commutative, then I run a**b-b**a and it gives 0

Does that happen even with a clean kernel? What version of Mathematica?

yes clean kernel mathematica 14.1

Ahh, new MMA version. Let me run some tests. Thanks Luca.

@Luca, just a follow up. I finally upgraded to 14.1 and ran all tests and I cannot reproduce your problem. Just to be sure, NCAlgebra version 6.0.3 is the latest. Did you get the message "NCAlgebra::SmallCapSymbolsNonCommutative: All lower cap single letter symbols (e.g. a,b,c,...) were set as noncommutative." after loading NCAlgebra?

Yes I also have NCAlgebra 6.0.3 and i get the loading message that lower cap single letter symbols are set to non commutative. then I immediately run a**b-b**a and get 0.

You need a few more rules: distribution, for example, is not obvious:
rules = {(u_ + v_) ** w_ -> u ** w + v ** w,
         u_ ** (v_ + w_) -> u ** v + u ** w,
         u_?NumericQ ** v_ -> u v,
         u_ ** v_?NumericQ -> u v};
ccr = {a ** ad -> ad ** a + 1};

comm[x_, y_] := x ** y - y ** x //. Join[rules, ccr]

comm[a + ad, a ** ad]
(*    a - ad    *)

If you want to use other variables that commute with $a$ and $a^+$, then you could define a commuteQ function that checks if a symbol $x$ commutes with everything:
ncvar = {a, ad};
commuteQ[x_] := AllTrue[ncvar, FreeQ[x, #] &]

The rules are now
rules = {(u_ + v_) ** w_ -> u ** w + v ** w,
         u_ ** (v_ + w_) -> u ** v + u ** w,
         u_?commuteQ ** v_ -> u v,
         u_ ** v_?commuteQ -> u v};

and we still have
comm[a + ad, a ** ad]
(*    a - ad    *)


Somehow it doesn't work for me. I have these things also coded up but I was expecting with NCAlgebra they would be redundant.

Oh You’re using a package? If so, please give the EXACT code that you’re using. The answers will be more accurate.

@Roman It is on github. Distributivity must be built in
